# Angular service, Trying to implement retrying $http.get. (Typescript)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Im trying to implement some offline support for my angular web-app but i cant get my simple retry function to work.
I have a service with the following code

```
constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService, private $interval: ng.IIntervalService, private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {           
        this.httpService = $http;
    }
getCategories(updatedFunction: Function) {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();

            this.httpService.get('/api/listCategories')
                .success((response) => {
                deferred.resolve(response);

            }).error(() => {
                this.$timeout(() => this.getCategories(), 10000);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And on the controller i have the following.

```
    service.getCategories().then(c => {
                //Stuff in here
            });
```

If im online the service works fine and i get the expected data. But if im offline at start i begin to receieve "GET http://correct_looking_path/ ERR_FAILED and if i step the js file i can se that it runs this.httpService.get method but instantly fails to .error().
Then i connect, but still i get the same error message and pattern. 
The httpService.get method runs every 10 seconds but fails all the time.

If i refresh it works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your .error() callback isn't connected to your deferred object. You might want to set up an optional TypeScript parameter to pass in the deferred object so that you can chain the recursive calls.

```
getCategories(updatedFunction: Function, deferror?: angular.IDeferred<{}>) {
    var deferred;
    if (deferor) {
        deferred = deferror;
    } else {
        deferred = this.$q.defer();
    }

    this.httpService.get('/api/listCategories')
        .success((response) => {
        deferred.resolve(response);

    }).error(() => {
        this.$timeout(() => this.getCategories(deffered), 10000);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanx, it wasnt the problem but it solved my next question why it didnt update the value :)

Comment: @JohanLindberg Glad you figured it out. Thanks for also posting your solution

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that i didn't have my api request(/api/listCategories) under the NETWORK: section in my .appcache file.
So it tried to use some cached resource that didnt exist instead of trying to make a real http request.